# Unity Profiler : Update.Preloading cpu spike

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, profiler

I'm using Unity 2019 and I'm trying to understand why I have CPU spike when I load a scene, empty or not.

This is what I have in the profilter when I load a scene with SceneManager.LoadScene(xxx) :

[image: Spike when I load a scene]

And the hierarchy :

[image]

The scene I load is empty (all gameobjects, canvas, scripts etc.. are disabled). I only have a camera.

On each scene I load I have `UpdatePreloading` and `Application.WaitForAsyncOperationToComplete` in the hierarchy, and I dont know why.

I disabled all my coroutines, I dont load the scene with LoadSceneAsync, so I dont know what are these "async operations to complete".

I tried to use the profiler with the editor on Windows or from my Android device but it's the same result.

Do you have any ideas ?

What `Loading.UpdatePreloading()` means ?

What `Application.WaitForAsyncOperationToComplete` means ?

On each scene load I have these spikes.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It appears this happens due to the PREVIOUS scene that loads your blank scene. Is there a lot of UI, or Audio / Textures / RenderTextures there? Try loading a blank scene from a totally blank scene.